# Why does Ubuntu on Virtual Box not recognize my existing os system?

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox

When I go to download Ubuntu in Virtual Box the system says "This computer currently has no detected operating system. What would you like to do?" This is on the 5th step of the install. The options are then to erase the entire disk or literally something else. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1442639/edit) to link to whatever instructions you are following that include a "5th step."

Comment: I assume you are not correct when you say this message is emitted when you "go to download Ubuntu" Instead I assume you get this error when you try to *install* Ubuntu in Virtualbox. Do you already have an OS installed in Virtualbox? If not, this message is utterly expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.